# Expected a long or a date string representation of a timestamp value Cassandra

Tags: json, cassandra

I'm trying to insert a row in a Cassandra table using the query below

`INSERT INTO battery_time_series_by_producer JSON '{"timestamp":1514413581,"customer":"com.fetchcore-cloud.local","stream":"/sw8/sensor/battery","producer":"freight18","data":{"battery_level":1,"is_charging":true,"timestamp":1514413581}}';`

and I get the following error

`Expected a long or a datestring representation of a timestamp value, but got an Integer: 1514413581`

The field timestamp in the table is indeed of the timestamp format. However, how can I convert this to a long given that this is just JSON

My version of Cassandra is 3.11.1

Comment: I think that cassandra cql tried to parse json object to closet data type, hence the value `1514413581` is converted to Int. If you are giving a larger number, it will be parsed as Long. One more point worth noting is that `timestamp` type is representing a number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as the epoch. The values in your example is very small for me (e.g. year 1970). In short, it's either to use string (e.g. "1514413581") in JSON object or pass recent timestamp value (e.g. 314431312345)

Comment: Um.. Thanks for the comment. I think it is something related to that. Just as a side note. I believe epoch time is the number of **seconds** since 1970. Which would make my date line up to around today. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time. How did you arrive at such a high value?

Comment: It's convention only, you can cross check from cassandra doc https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html?hl=timestamp%2Ctype

Comment: @Apolozeus That is fascinating..! Converting the seconds to milliseconds solved it. If you write it up as an answer I'll accept :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra will try to parse json object to closest data type possible, e.g. the value 1514413581 is converted to Integer type. If you are giving a larger number, it will be parsed as Long.

Kindly note that that timestamp type is representing a number of **milliseconds** since the standard base time known as the [epoch](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html?hl=timestamp%2Ctype). The values in your example represent the time in year 1970.

In short, it's either to use string format (e.g. "1514413581") or pass recent timestamp value (which automatically convert to Long later) in your cql statement. Hope it helps.